# webdriver + reset Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to 'reset' Chrome browser using webdriver(python). What I'm doing is:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>
> driver.get('chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings')

above shows pop-up with 'reset' button, and I can't locate it using

> driver.find_element_somehow

please help me find a way to click 'reset' button.

Note: I also was trying to wipe all the files from '~/.config/google-chrome/' but that didn't serve needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution, hope will help someone.
it was in iframe, so I did:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('settings')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
main_window_handle = None
while not main_window_handle:
    main_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
popup_handle = None
while not popup_handle:
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if handle != main_window_handle:
            popup_handle = handle
            break
driver.switch_to.window(popup_handle)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'XPATH OF RESET BUTTON').click()
driver.switch_to.window(main_window_handle)
```

I think `switch_to.window(handle)` is deprecated lately, so instead of that, use:

```
switch_to_window(handle)
```

Comment: unfortunately, selenium still not being able to locate element and throws an exception